# For a continuous function with $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx=1$, and $M=\max{f(x)}$, show that $1-\frac{1}{2M}\geq\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx\geq\frac{1}{2M}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For $f:[0,1]{\rightarrow}[0,\infty]$ a continuous function with $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx=1$, and $M=\max{f(x)}$, show that $1-\frac{1}{2M}\geq\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx\geq\frac{1}{2M}$. Supposing that $M<1$, I obtained a contradiction , because it would result that $f(x)<1$ and so $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)<1$, thus $1<1$,false. So, $M>1$, and $\int_{0}^{ 1} F(x)dx=1-\int_{0}^{1} xf(x)dx.$, where $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(x)$. If $F(x)>1$, $F(x)>\frac{x}{M}$ and so $\int_{0}^{1} F(x)>\frac{1}{2M}$ and thus the right side of the inequality to be proven is shown to be true. For $M=1$, the left side is also easily proved from $\int_{0}^{1} (f(x)-M)(x-1)dx\geq0$ and $\frac{M}{2}-1+\frac{1}{2M}$. However, it depends on assuming that the primitive is bigger than 1. As it is increasing over $[0,\infty]$, from a point on it's bigger than $F(1)=1$, but I am not sure my progress it's a solution.

Comment: Using the function $F$ is a good idea, but I don't follow your argument (if F(x)>1...), since $0 \leq F(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the antiderivative $F$ of $f$ defined by:

$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt.$$

$F$ is defined on $[0,1]$ (and not a larger domain, as $f$ itself is only defined on $[0,1]$). From the hypotheses, we know that $F$ is nondecreasing, $F(0)=0$, $F(1)=1$, $F$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, and $F'(x) \leq M$ for all $x$. Hence:

- for $x \in [0,1/M]$: $F(x) \leq \int_0^x M dt = Mx$.
- for $x \in [1/m, 1]$: $F(x) \leq 1$.

By integration by part,

$$\int_0^1 xf(x)dx = 1 \cdot F(1)- 0 \cdot F(0) - \int_0^1 F(x) dx$$

$$ = \int_0^1 (1-F(x)) dx \geq \int_0^{1/M} (1-Mt) dt = \frac{1}{2M}.$$

The upper bound should follow by the change of variable $u=1-x$. Let $g(x) := f(1-x)$; then $g$ satisfies the same conditions, and:

$$\int_0^1 xf(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x)dx - \int_0^1 (1-x)f(x)dx = 1-\int_0^1 ug(u)du.$$

The lower bound on $\int_0^1 ug(u)du$ yields the upper bound on $\int_0^1 xf(x)dx$.

Not that this exercise is in some sense about [stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance), and the distribution function $F$ is a low-level way of formulating and manipulating this notion.